# Show live location over google maps using (constantly updating) Lat, Long from Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on android application in which i am storing/updating live coordinates (Lat, Long) of device in database MySQL.
Now i want to display those coordinates over google maps Which i am doing using

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps

My problem is how to constantly update or Repeatedly Fetch the updated Latitude and Longitude from my database (mySql) and display live location over map?

I have written my web services in php. The solution in the link is not final and Any help is appreciated. [Database Table structure is attached. Here i am storing / updating the live location coordinates against each CNIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCfzZ.jpg)

Comment: use ajax to get the live coordinates and update the location on map, Or you can try node.js to live stream the coordinates to your browser.

Comment: Can you please give a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to update latitude and longitude constantly, you must 
prepare as follows.

First, server side program (fetch latitude and longitude from your 
database and send these data to your client).

Second, client device (recieve latitude and longitude) .

Third, javascript program (display marker and other icons).